# launcher for a program not working - ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, launcher, unity-dash

I'm using a program named "robomongo" (a mongoDB UI), but to run it I need to type in the terminal "./robomongo.sh".

I tried to add the file `~/.local/share/applications/robomongo.desktop`
Like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=robo-mongo
Comment=robomongo
Exec=/opt/robo/robomongo.sh
Terminal=flase
Categories=Application;
```

And it's still not working from the dash. (I can see the app in the dash when I start typing robo, but it's not doing anyhting).

Please guide me, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you make `robomongo.sh` executable by chmod? `sudo chmod +x robomongo.sh`

Comment: yep, tried that ...

Comment: Should that be `Terminal=false` rather than `Terminal=flase`?

Comment: yes, but that's not the problem. I tried "false"/"true" already... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by editing the robomongo.sh script, changing the relative paths to absolute paths (eg: ./lib to /opt/robomongo/lib).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/whats-new-in/robomongo-0.8.0.html) version 0.8.0 and newer, there's a desktop entry made available if you install the application from the `.deb` package.

Comment: for version 0.9.0 there is no debian package available